# EF code first migration - Change Sql Azure table key

Tags: ef-code-first, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

Sql Azure does not support changing a table key. There is a work around: create a new table, transfer the data, delete the old table.

Because of this limitation, EF (4.3) is not able to migrate my model after changing a table's key.

What can I do to get EF code first to accept the new database after applying the manual work around? (Without having to drop the entire database or touch other tables)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of manual editing you can get everything of this done inside a code based migration.

- Change the key in your model (through annotations or the fluent API).
- Run `add-migration` from the package manager console to get a new code based migration.
- Exchange the generated migration steps in the migration file with the create-transfer-delete-rename method required by Azure.

Now when you run the application, the update to change keys will be done using your custom migration steps fit for Azure, rather than the default code.

Comment: Hmm I understand the first 2 steps, but what does this "create-transfer-delete-rename" method look like?

Comment: "create-transfer-delete-rename" was meant as the work around you outlined yourself, although i might not be exactly delete-rename if Azure doesn't allow renaming. You have to check what works. The idea is to change the code generated with whatever code is required to work with Azure.